# Python. Pandas. Минимум и его индекс

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame:

```
    0         1         2          3          4          5
0 NaN  2.828427  3.162278  10.198039  12.165525  13.601471
1 NaN       NaN  3.162278   8.944272  10.770330  12.529964
2 NaN       NaN       NaN   7.071068   9.055385  10.440307
3 NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN   2.000000   3.605551
4 NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN   2.236068
5 NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

С `x.min()` получается:

```
0         NaN
1    2.828427
2    3.162278
3    7.071068
4    2.000000
5    2.236068
```

С `min(x.min()[2:])` получается: `2.0`.
Как вытащить 2 вместе с ее индексом 4?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826232/pandas-locate-minimum-of-dataframe-matrix-index-col

Comment: @splash58
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначала можно получить вектор с минимумами столбцов, а потом получить из него абсолютный минимум и его индекс, воспользовавшись [Series.idxmin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
mn = df.min()
min_, min_idx = mn.min(), mn.idxmin()
print(f"min: {min_}, min_index: {min_idx}")
# min: 2.0, min_index: 4
```